# Add and retrieve elements with Numbers array in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, numbers

My Android program utilizes a Graph API/.jar (android plot core) and this requires the graph numbers to be stored in a Numbers[].

Currently it looks like:
Numbers[] series1Numbers = {1,2,3,4}

How do I add elements to the array? And how do I retrieve elements from it in a loop? I cannot do .add(mynumber) or .get(number).

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: use List or concatenate two arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [List](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html) (e.g. ArrayList) instead.

And before passing it to the Graph API convert it back to Numbers[] array with [toArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[])).

There's also an example how to loop over the list in the toArray link.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can not add more elements, given that your array can have only 4 elements. I would use an ArrayList in your position. If you really need to use arrays, create a new Array, copy the data, and then add the new element:

```
Numbers[] serie2 = Numbers[5];
Java.lang.System.arraycopy(series1Numbers, 0, serie2, 0, 4);
serie2[4]=///add whatever you wanted to add
```

Regarding the loop, there are many tutorials out there.
https://blog.udemy.com/for-each-loop-java/

Answer (score 0):

Using a list might be more convenient in this case, you can use an ArrayList that does not have a specific size, you can add an element by just using .add(element).